# VS2012 and Entity Framework 6.1.3 compatibility

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-migrations

I am using VS2012 and trying to run a code I have received from a colleague (who happens to use VS2013). He is using EF (v 6.1.3) Code-First New Database approach.

Now I am trying to enable the migrations to create the database, but Package Manager Console is unable to identify Enable-Migrations code.

Below is the error I receive (please click the image to enlarge)
[image]

- I have installed [EF Tools for VS2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762), but that does't resolve the issue. Even [Microsoft tells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574253.aspx) that it can only resolve EF Code-First Existing Database problems.
- I don't know if I have to rollback `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms v1.1.0` to a previous version.

Any help on this is appreciated.

**Edit**
Error tells that I need a newer Nuget version, but VS2012 doesn't support Nuget v2.12

Comment: Have you tried updating your nuget version like the error says (easiest way is in extension manager)?

Comment: Yup, I did. VS2012 doesn't support Nuget 2.12

Comment: To be fair 2012 is almost 3 versions old. Maybe its time to upgrade, its even free for community which is pretty good

Comment: You should be able to run migrations outside VS with the migrate.exe tool if nothing else works.

Comment: You cannot use .NET Core dependencies in VS 2012

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Yup we are considering an update sometime in near future, thank you.

Comment: @Pawal: I'll try it, haven't known about a migrate tool. Is it what used for production deployment?

Comment: @ErikEJ: So does it imply that I may have to lower the EF version to best fit VS2012?

Comment: No, it was just a comment on the other (unrelated) Nuget error - EF 6 works fine with VS 2012